# Use webflux to make asynchronous calls and then perform task on response

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I need to make concurrent calls to an API with paginated responses and then perform asyonchronous tasks on each item of each of the responses.
A friend of mine suggested WebFlux was the way to go about this so I decided to give it a change but it proving very difficult to use without proper training and I'm very new at this.

I have concurrently to get the first 5 pages of an API (10 items per page) and concurrently save an image using each of the item's url value. There's no need to wait for a response.

MyService

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://host");

    public void downloadImages() {
        List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
                .boxed().toList();
        Flux.fromIterable(range)
                .flatMap(pageNumber -> fetchPages(pageNumber), 10); //10 asynchronous calls
    }

    private Flux<APIResponse> fetchPages(int page) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("/images?page={page}", page)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(APIResponse.class)
                .flatMap(response -> downloadImage(response));
    }

    //What does this method actually looks like? Publisher was auto-completed. 
    // It needs to iterate each actual response
    // as it becomes availables and perform 
    private Publisher downloadImages(APIResponse response) {
        //download each image using url of response.getImages();
        //best to do parallelStream foreach for this task?
        // or use a thread pool to download each image?

        response.getImages().forEach(System.out::println); //this is never executed
        return null; //what's a publisher?
    }
}
```

My APIResponse has an Image object like this:

```
@Data
public class ImageResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String imageURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost : a `Publisher` is the parent class of `Mono` and `Flux`. It is defined in [reactivestream API](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/latest/org/reactivestreams/Publisher.html) as the value producer (the stream source). A `Mono` is a specialization that sends 0 or 1 element, and a Flux is a specialization that sends 0 to many elements.

Also, generally, a publisher is not triggered  until subscription (subscribe() or block()). Generally, in a Spring app, the flux or Mono is propagated to the web (your rest controller or request router) or database layer (reactive/r2dbc repository), which will be responsible for subscribing to the flux.
Although, you are still allowed to subscribe yourself, but then it becomes your responsibility to consume elements and schedule tasks on the right [Scheduler](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html).

The service could be rework as follows if you download image raw content:

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://host");

    /**
     * @return One data buffer per fetched image. 
     */
    public Flux<DataBuffer> downloadImages() {
        return Flux.range(1, 5)
                   .flatMap(this::fetchPages, 10)
                   .flatMap(this::downloadImage);
    }

    private Flux<APIResponse> fetchPages(int page) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("/images?page={page}", page)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(APIResponse.class);
    }

    
    private Flux<DataBuffer> downloadImages(APIResponse response) {
        return response.getImages()
                       .flatMap(this::downloadImage);
    }

    private Mono<DataBuffer> downloadImage(URL imageUrl) {
        return webClient.get().uri(url)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono<DataBuffer>()
    }
}
```

In a unit test, you can then use [reactor test API](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html) to test it like so:

```java
StepVerifier.create(myService.downloadImages())
            // Number of images you expect to download
            .expectNextCount(2)
            .verifyComplete();
```